# Deploy Ubuntu 2004 EN but with swiss french keyboard layout

Tags: debian, preseed, configure, kickstart

I am deploying Ubuntu Focal fossa via Network boot with a preseed file ubuntu_config.cfg.

Inside this file I have this:

```
..
d-i debian-installer/language string en
d-i debian-installer/country string CH
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US.UTF-8
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i keyboard-configuration/layoutcode string ch(fr)
d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select ch(fr)
etc..
...
```

the Problem is that the Ubuntu Focal fossa version 2004 deploys correctly But The Keyboard layout is Swiss-german. I have watched at the several Ubuntu [documentations](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/mips/apbs04.html.de)  and It seems that with generic  keyboard layouts like German (de) or french (fr) it works fine
. But I am not shure how to do it with swiss french layout (the problem is that the french layout is quite different from the swiss-french layout). any Ideas?

Comment: Are you using the Ubuntu Desktop installer or the legacy Server installer?  What does `localectl status` and `cat /etc/default/keyboard` show on the installed system?

Comment: Hi thanks for asking. I am using The Ubuntu Desktop Installer.

Comment: I used your config with the legacy server installer and the commands I listed both showed `ch(fr)` was being used.  The desktop installer may have its own quirks though.  Both of these installers are based on `debian-installer`, but the desktop installer has different customization.